# Drupal 8 cache not cleared in development mode

Tags: caching, drupal-8, drupal-console

I'm working on a new Drupal 8 project and ran the drupal console "drupal site:mode dev" command. After I created some custom blocks, views or content types. I noticed that when I make changes to template files, the cache isn't cleared automatically.

I've checked the service.yml file, and everything looks the same as previous projects I've been working on. I could narrow the issue down to render cache (probably). I've also noticed that it only occurs with custom created entities. (like mentioned above). Anyone an idea what the issue could be? I'm already looking for this several days.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check again your **services.yml** file, to disable cache on *twig templates* you must have these values:

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Hope that helps!

More information: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914